# How to connect socket server to nestJs microservice (not in api-gateway)

Tags: sockets, websocket, nestjs, microservices

How can i create socket connection in auth microservice like api-gateway. I am using nestJs.

**API-gateway main.ts**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bodyParser: false,
  });
const port = process.env.PORT || 3333;
  await app.listen(port);

}

bootstrap();
```

**Auth microservice main.ts(without any port)**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,
      options: {
        client: {
          brokers: [process.env.SERVICE_KAFKA_BROKER],
        },
        consumer: {
          groupId: 'auth-consumer',
        },
      },
    }
  );
  await app.listen();
}

bootstrap();
```

Socket in api-gateway(with port) is working fine with the following code,
**In auth microservice I did the same but not works.**

```
  @WebSocketGateway({
      cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      },
    })

export class AuthGateway implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor() {}

  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  onModuleInit() {
    this.server.on('connection', (_socket) => {
       //for api gateway connected logged to the console.
       //but in auth-microservice i can't find the log.
      console.log("connected");
  })

}
```

Comment: I believe for the websocket integration there has to be an HTTP adapter running, so you'd need a [hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application) for your microservice server